# Insertar emojis en mysql 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, genexus

Quiero insertar textos que tienen emojis en una tabla MySQL. Vi que se necesita 4 bytes por cada emoji porque vienen en 2 hexadecimales. El tema que he visto por ahí diferentes "soluciones" y ninguna me funcionó.

Va parte del error:

> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   com.genexus.GXRuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect
>   string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x98\xF0\x9F...' for column 'TweetText' at
>   row 1     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2693)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2102)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2395)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2298)
>     at com.genexus.db.driver.GXPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.genexus.db.UpdateCursor.postExecute(Unknown Source)
>     at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(Unknown Source)

Alguien sabe como configurar el `mysql`, o el `client.cfg` o algún workarround para lograr insertar en la BD emojis??

El código simplificado sería algo así, siendo `&Tweet` una variable de tipo **Business Component** en **GeneXus** y `&itemresult` el tweet resultado de hacer un llamado a una API de Twitter:

```
&Tweet.TweetId=&itemresult.id_str
&Tweet.TweetText=&itemresult.text
&Tweet.Save()
commit
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola CarboneroManya. Sería bueno si indicas un ejemplo en código de cómo estás intentando registrar el texto del emoji en tu cadena de texto.

Comment: Por ejemplo quiero insertar este texto en el campo tweettext que al final tiene emojis en ="RT kstatesports: Hey SportsCenter, how about a #SCTop10 tip of the cap to #KStateBSB's Jake Wodtke with his glovely catch today?\ud83d\udc4f\ud83c\udffb\u26be\ufe0f\nhttp\u2026"

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el ejemplo en código por favor? Es decir, edita tu pregunta, agrega un ejemplo de cómo te da error, y así lo podemos revisar mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente el "character set" por defecto en MySQL es `utf8` que soporta caracteres UNICODE de largo entre 1 y 3 bytes, por lo que los emoji no están soportados con esta configuración.

A partir de MySQL 5.5.3, se agregó un nuevo "character set" de nombre `utf8mb4` que sí soporta emoji.

Citando la [documentación de MySQL (en inglés)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html):

> The character set named utf8 uses a maximum of three bytes per character and contains only BMP characters. As of MySQL 5.5.3, the utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character [...]

Traducción:

> El conjunto de caracteres `utf8` usa un máximo de tres bytes por carácter y contiene solamente caracteres BMP. A partir de MySQL 5.5.3, el conjunto de caracteres `utf8mb4` usa un máximo de cuatro bytes por carácter [...]

Hasta donde sé GeneXus no soporta esta configuración al momento de crear la base de datos, pero puedes probar un `ALTER DATABASE` para cambiar esta configuración luego de creada ([ver documentación de MySQL, en inglés](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html)).

Comment: Hola Marcos gracias x tu respuesta , le puse Charset: utf8mb4 a la tabla en cuestión. Y me cambió el collation a utf8mb4_general_ci también. Probé insertar y me salta el mismo error :(( Leí x ahí que hay que mandarle a la conexión algún parámetro pero no logro entender que mandar, ni como.....

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el tema, paso a contarles como:

Actualicé el `CHARACTER SET` y el `COLLATE` de la base de datos de `utf8` a `utf8mb4`. Sucede que MySQL utiliza 3 bytes para almacenar los caracteres utf8 y 4 bytes para los catacteres utf8mb4, de manera que este último sí soporta todos los bytes de los emojis. Asimismo, actualicé el `CHARACTER SET` y `COLLATE` de las tablas relevantes.

La explicación de este paso la encontré en
http://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database

Luego vi que estaba usando la librería mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin.jar que trae Genexus Evo3 y Salto por defecto y lo copia al WEB-INF/lib del tomcat. Descargué una versión más actual: mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar y se solucionó.

Comment: Actualicé tu respuesta para que sea auto contenida. Es decir, que el texto por sí solo pueda explicar cómo resolver el problema. Recuerda que los enlaces o links son para agregar información adicional o sustentar lo que se indica en la respuesta, los enlaces **no son** la respuesta. Esto se realiza porque los enlaces pueden expirar (si son enlaces al sitio interno, las preguntas/respuestas pueden ser eliminadas (!) así que cuidado). Asimismo, edité un poco de ortografía y gramática.